# Understanding SignInAdapter in spring-social

Tags: java, signing, spring-social

Hello guys i read a lot about Spring-Social and i have a question. What is a parameter "userLocalId" in signIn method of SignInAdapter where it takes this id? I register user via facebook by fetching it information in register form. After this i want that he press signIn_button(facebook signIn) and have access to my site.

Should i do something like this: in SignInAdapter i getting connection to facebook and compare it's social information with fields in my users table?

Answer (score 3):

The Spring Social Integration has 3 parts.

- Signup
  In Signup a local user is created based on the information provided by the provider
- Connect
  In connect we map a local user to the openID user
- Signin
  In signin we allows a openId authenticated user to log in to our application

**Signin**
In signin the `SigninAdapter` is used to load the local user so that the Spring Security layer can use it. Here the `localUserId` parameter will point to the Id of the user in our application. So in the adapter we need to load this user as an `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` and set it to the `SecurityContext`.

ex:

```
LocalUser lu = getLocalUser(localUserId); // Load the local user from database
User user = new User(lu.username, lu.password, lu.authorities)
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
```

**Connect**
Spring Social Providers a `org.springframework.social.connect.web.ConnectController` which will help us to link a local user to a openId user.
It requires you to send a `POST` request to `/connect/<provider>`, this will redirect the user to the login page of the provider where the user has to autherize the application.

Comment: Yeah thx. But how can i use connect part if the user already sign in by my own login system.